# Specify database backend store creation in specific schema

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mlflow

When creating an mlflow tracking server and specifying that a SQL Server database is to be used as a backend store, mlflow creates a bunch of table within the dbo schema. Does anyone know if it is possible to specify a different schema in which to create these tables?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to alter `mlflow/mlflow/store/sqlalchemy_store.py` to change the schema of the tables that are stored.

It is very likely that this is the wrong solution for you, since you will go out of sync with the open source and lose newer features that alter this, unless you maintain the fork yourself. Could you maybe reply with your use case?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using MSSQLServer as the backend store. I could use a different schema than dbo by specifying the default schema for the SQLServer user being used by MLFlow.

In my case, if the MLFlow tables (e.g: experiences) exist in dbo, then those tables will be used. If not, MLFlow will create those tables in the default schema.

Answer (score 1):

You can use postgres uri options:

Postgres URI options sample:

"postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres?options=-csearch_path%3Ddbo,mlflow_schema"

In your Mlflow Code:

mlflow.set_tracking_uri("postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres?options=-csearch_path%3Ddbo,mlflow_schema")

! Don't forget to create 'mlflow_schema' schema.

[how-to-specify-schema-in-psycopg2-connection-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59298580/how-to-specify-schema-in-psycopg2-connection-method)