# How to specify Schema in psycopg2 connection method?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Using the psycopg2 module to connect to the PostgreSQL database using python. Able to execute all queries using the below connection method. Now I want to specify a different schema than public to execute my SQL statements. Is there any way to specify the schema name in the connection method?

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost",
                            port="5432",
                            user="postgres",
                            password="password",
                            database="database",
                            )
```

I tried to specify schema directly inside the method.
`schema="schema2"`
But I am getting the following programming error.

```
ProgrammingError: invalid dsn: invalid connection option "schema"
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When we were working on `ThreadConnectionPool` which is in `psycopg2` and creating connection pool, this is how we did it.

```
from psycopg2.pool import ThreadedConnectionPool

db_conn = ThreadedConnectionPool(
    minconn=1, maxconn=5,
    user="postgres", password="password", database="dbname", host="localhost", port=5432,
    options="-c search_path=dbo,public"
)
```

You see that `options` key there in params. That's how we did it.

When you execute a query using the cursor from that connection, it will search across those schemas mentioned in `options` i.e., `dbo,public` in sequence from left to right.

You may try something like this:

```
psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", 
                 port="5432", 
                 user="postgres", 
                 password="password", 
                 database="database", 
                 options="-c search_path=dbo,public")
```

Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 24):

If you are using the string form you need to URL escape the `options` argument:

```
postgresql://localhost/airflow?options=-csearch_path%3Ddbo,public
```

(`%3D` = URL encoding of `=`)

This helps if you are using SQLAlchemy for example.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me, but we can use "=" instead of %3D while migrating.