# Psycopg search path error when using dblink internally

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have the followinf connection using psycopg:

```
 conn = psycopg2.connect(
            host=os.environ['DATABASE_HOST'],
            port=os.environ['DATABASE_PORT'],
            database=str(base64.b64decode(
                os.environ['DATABASE_NAME']).decode('utf-8')),
            user=str(base64.b64decode(
                os.environ['DATABASE_USER']).decode('utf-8')),
            password=str(base64.b64decode(
                os.environ['DATABASE_PASSWORD']).decode('utf-8')),
            options=f'-c search_path=my_og.my_schema'
        )
```

and I have a function call as follows:

```
cur.execute('SELECT get_data( %s,%s,%s); ',(str(month), str(year), str(region))
```

Now on the Postgres side, I am calling another function `run_consolidattion` and it is using `DBLink`. This DBLink is created in `public` schema, but I need to specify the `search_path` as `my_og.my_schema` and `get_data` function is in this schema. So when I execute my query, I am getting the following error:

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: function dblink(text, text) does not exist
2022-08-24T06:47:15.003662811Z LINE 1: SELECT * FROM dblink(db_string,'select * from (select...
```

HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

I am assuming this is because of the schema mismatch, as the `get_data` call is working fine from the PgAdmin side and it is showing this from Python.

How can I solve this error ? I am not sure, how to pass the public schema, as the DBLink is referenced internally. I tried to change the `search_path` option to the public, but then the `get_data` function is not working as there is no such function in the public schema.

Comment: Have you tried to specify two schemas in search_path?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59298745/19032206

Comment: `SELECT * FROM public.dblink(...`.